# Не инициализируются переменные в C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, инициализация

Всем привет. У меня такая проблема: не могу понять почему переменные в моём коде не инициализируются. По идее переменные должны инициализироваться данными из текстового файла, но этого не происходит и Visual Studio выдаёт предупреждения об инициализации. Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class NOTE {
private:
    int year, day, month, housenum, flat, i, m, y = 0, N;
    char surname[15], name[15], name2[15], city[15], street[15], phone[15];
public:
    void PrintRead() {
        ifstream fread;
        fread.open("list.txt");
        if (!fread.is_open()) {
            perror("Произошла ошибка при открытии файла\n");
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }
        cout << "Выводим информации о людях из текстового файла.";
        fread >> N;
        cout << "\nЛюдей всего: " << N;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            fread >> NOTE1[i].surname >> NOTE1[i].name >> NOTE1[i].name2 >> NOTE1[i].phone >> NOTE1[i].city
                >> NOTE1[i].street >> NOTE1[i].housenum >> NOTE1[i].flat >> NOTE1[i].day >> NOTE1[i].month >> NOTE1[i].year;
            cout << "\n\nДанные человека №" << i + 1
                << "\nФИО: " << NOTE1[i].surname << " " << NOTE1[i].name << " " << NOTE1[i].name2
                << "\nНомер телефона: " << NOTE1[i].phone
                << "\nАдрес: г. " << NOTE1[i].city << ", ул. " << NOTE1[i].street << ", д. " << NOTE1[i].housenum << ", кв. " << NOTE1[i].flat
                << "\nДата рождения: " << NOTE1[i].day << "." << NOTE1[i].month << "." << NOTE1[i].year;
        }
        fread.close();
    }
    void Sorting() {
        sort(
            NOTE1, NOTE1 + N,
            [](NOTE const& lhs, NOTE const& rhs)->bool {
                return lhs.day < rhs.day;
            }
        );
        sort(
            NOTE1, NOTE1 + N,
            [](NOTE const& lhs, NOTE const& rhs)->bool {
                return lhs.month < rhs.month;
            }
        );
        sort(
            NOTE1, NOTE1 + N,
            [](NOTE const& lhs, NOTE const& rhs)->bool {
                return lhs.year < rhs.year;
            }
        );
    }
    void PrintWrite() {
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("rezult.txt");
        if (!fout.is_open()) {
            perror("Произошла ошибка при открытии файла\n");
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }
        cout << "\n\nОтсортированный список по дням рождениям:\n";
        fout << "Отсортированный список по дням рождениям:\n";
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            cout << "\nФИО: " << NOTE1[i].surname << " " << NOTE1[i].name << " " << NOTE1[i].name2
                << "\nНомер телефона: " << NOTE1[i].phone
                << "\nАдрес: г. " << NOTE1[i].city << ", ул. " << NOTE1[i].street << ", д. " << NOTE1[i].housenum << ", кв. " << NOTE1[i].flat
                << "\nДата рождения: " << NOTE1[i].day << "." << NOTE1[i].month << "." << NOTE1[i].year << "\n";
            fout << "\nФИО: " << NOTE1[i].surname << " " << NOTE1[i].name << " " << NOTE1[i].name2
                << "\nНомер телефона: " << NOTE1[i].phone
                << "\nАдрес: г. " << NOTE1[i].city << ", ул. " << NOTE1[i].street << ", д. " << NOTE1[i].housenum << ", кв. " << NOTE1[i].flat
                << "\nДата рождения: " << NOTE1[i].day << "." << NOTE1[i].month << "." << NOTE1[i].year << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\nСписок родившихся в месяце(месяц ввести в числовом формате):";
        fout << "\nСписок родившихся в месяце(месяц ввести в числовом формате):";
        cin >> m;
        fout << m;
        if (m < 1 || m>12) {
            cout << "\nМесяц указан не верно\n";
            fout << "\n\nМесяц указан не верно";
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                if (m == NOTE1[i].month) {
                    cout << "\nФИО: " << NOTE1[i].surname << " " << NOTE1[i].name << " " << NOTE1[i].name2
                        << "\nНомер телефона: " << NOTE1[i].phone
                        << "\nАдрес: г. " << NOTE1[i].city << ", ул. " << NOTE1[i].street << ", д. " << NOTE1[i].housenum << ", кв. " << NOTE1[i].flat
                        << "\nДата рождения: " << NOTE1[i].day << "." << NOTE1[i].month << "." << NOTE1[i].year << "\n";
                    fout << "\nФИО: " << NOTE1[i].surname << " " << NOTE1[i].name << " " << NOTE1[i].name2
                        << "\nНомер телефона: " << NOTE1[i].phone
                        << "\nАдрес: г. " << NOTE1[i].city << ", ул. " << NOTE1[i].street << ", д. " << NOTE1[i].housenum << ", кв. " << NOTE1[i].flat
                        << "\nДата рождения: " << NOTE1[i].day << "." << NOTE1[i].month << "." << NOTE1[i].year << "\n";
                    y++;
                }
            }
            if (y == 0) {
                cout << "\nЛюдей родившихся в " << m << " месяце - нет\n";
                fout << "\n\nЛюдей родившихся в " << m << " месяце - нет";
            }
        }
        fout.close();
    }
}*NOTE1;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    NOTE People;
    People.PrintRead();
    People.Sorting();
    People.PrintWrite();
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: переменная `*NOTE1;` это нулевой указатель. Он ничего не может получить. Где-то нужно выделить память `fread >> N; NOTE1 = new NOTE [ N ] ;` И объявить эту переменную **перед** функциями, чтобы всё скомпилировалось : `class NOTE * NOTE1  ;`

Comment: .. а вообще нужно разделить класс `NOTE` на два класса, один `Person` с данными персон, а второй с вашими функциями, вспомогательными переменными и этим указателем `NOTE * NOTE1 ;`

Comment: И сортировка вот так, тремя функциями, работать не будет (по крайней мере, гарантированно). Просто потому, что `sort` — сортировка *неустойчивая*. Лучше набросать один компаратор, тем более что он несложный. Можно использовать стандартный [`tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). А еще о самом проекте... Функции у вас слишком сложные и всеобъемлющие, но, возможно, это просто на мой вкус :)

Comment: Теперь данные стали выводиться корректно. Спасибо большое, @AlexGlebe!

Comment: Теперь буду разбираться с сортировкой.

Comment: @AlexGlebe можете пожалуйста подсказать? Где именно  в коде нужно выделять память `fread >> N; NOTE1 = new NOTE [ N ] ;`?

Comment: `cout << "Выводим информации о людях из текстового файла.";
        fread >> N; NOTE1 = new NOTE [ N ] ;
        cout << "\nЛюдей всего: " << N;`

Comment: Да, я так и делал, но ведь это работает только тогда когда у меня одна подпрограмма в классе, если я ввожу `class NOTE * NOTE1; NOTE1 = new NOTE[N];` в `void Sorting()` и  `void PrintWrite()`, данные полученные из файла, не сохраняются, а если я ввожу просто `class NOTE * NOTE1` в `void Sorting()` и  `void PrintWrite()` то компилятор пишет: "использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "NOTE1"".